# MX record and google apps for work

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform

I've recently started using the google cloud platform and I'm a little confused about where to place the MX record.

My setup of my domain is as follows:

I registered a domain through namecheap.com and setup a virtual machine on the google compute engine with a static IP, for this VM I deployed a WordPress platform. Then I created a cloud DNS server zone using the IP of the VM as the A record and then added the records for the CNAME and NS.

From namecheap.com I updated the name servers with the googles name servers. On top of this I created a CloudFlare account and updated namecheap.com DNS servers again this time with CloudFlares new DNS servers so that now Cloudflare is the authoritative DNS server and the google cloud DNS I created is the recursive DNS.

My question is where do I appropriately place the MX record for my domain, would I only add it to google cloud DNS or as well as the CloudFlare DNS, would placing the MX record at both locations cause issues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would place the MX record on the CloudFlare DNS server, because as you stated its the authoritative DNS server, meaning that is the DNS server that will be queried for the correct DNS records. You can place the MX record on the google DNS servers for redundancy. IE, in the event CloudFlare DNS servers are having a problem or someone for whatever reason has a routing problem to those DNS servers, google dns servers can pick it up and still point to the appropriate place.

The only thing to ensure is that on both DNS servers, everything matches otherwise you can run into some problems with DNS resolving to wrong locations etc.

To add on, you can have more than 1 Authoritative DNS server assigned to a domain, which is different than a recursive DNS server. In this case, the first Authoritative DNS server assigned to the DNS server is queried first, then the second and so forth. Recursive dns servers are used to help point those trying to connect to a domain to the right place, and if it doesn't have the records cached, it contacts the Authoritative DNS servers for those records.